# How to sent custom notification with url to app users?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to sent url to user using firebase console and how to do that?
When the user clicks the notification, the browser or chooser have to open and url must be loaded. 
Please help with firebase console where the url and key are placed and sent the notification and show where this key is in the java file.
Thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow. If you don't know where to start, read up on Push Notification, GCM / FCM, and Android Notifications. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: i have seen notification in android but does,t know how to use using it over internet.

Comment: You need your app to subscribe for GCM / FCM, then send your token to the server that will use the token to send out Push Notifications. Once you received a Push Notification on your mobile, you handle it by either showing something in your app, or showing a Notification. There are tons of tutorials on the internet, just google for Push notifications on Android, GCM / FCM etc.