# Send URL in push notification Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

My application is currently receiving Text, Image and both as a push notification from Firebase console. I want to send a URL too as a notification from my Firebase console to the app user. On clicking the notification. user shall be redirected to the specific URL, e.g. `www.google.com` .How can I do this in following code?

```
package com.example.khan.andronotification;

/**
 * Created by AndroidBash on 20-Aug-16.
 */
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
    Bitmap bitmap;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        //
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
        //You can change as per the requirement.

        //message will contain the Push Message
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
        String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
        String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

        //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

        sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    /*
    *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got the desired result. please post your code as Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite onMessageReceived as in here ( [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) ) and then set the URL of it as in here ( [Opening a browser link through notification isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232288/opening-a-browser-link-through-notification-isnt-working) ).

Comment: Well, the author answered to somebody, we will never know who. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175655/android-push-notification-url.