# Android Push Notification URL

Tags: android, firebase

My application is currently receiving Text , Image and both as a push notification from Firebase console. I want to send URL too as a notification from my Firebase console to the app user.On clicking the notification user shall be redirected to the specific url i.e. www.facebook.com .How can i do this in following code?
[Kindly see the image thats what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na8ap.png)

[Image From firebase notification console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na8ap.png)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
    Bitmap bitmap;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        //
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
        //You can change as per the requirement.

        //message will contain the Push Message
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
        String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
        String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

        //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

        sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    /*
    *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na8ap.png

Comment: just like other fields use any key value and retrieve that in your reciever

Comment: As according to above code on clicking notification we shall redirected to activity not browser

Comment: look below my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the code that i have implemented in my app for pushing link with data

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
Bitmap bitmap;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    String link=remoteMessage.getData().get("link");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);
    sendNotification(message, bitmap,link);

}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String link) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("LINK",link);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}}
```

And this is MainActivity to open link in my WebView or other browser depand on your requirement through intents.

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("LINK")!=null) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,WebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("link",getIntent().getStringExtra("LINK"));
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }}
```

Now in WebViewActivity get link and load url in WebView

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String url = i.getStringExtra("link");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: @Shubham Shukla, what is BrowserActivity,NewsListActivity ? can you edit you answer by using only mainactivity and MyFirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: @ChrisHarris i have edited the answer and webviewactivity contains a webview to load url

Comment: @Shubham, When sending custom data through notification, Is "LINK" is the key and "http://www.fb.com" is the value? It's not working. Can you post the WebViewActivity and MainActivity please.