How can I add a URL on a firebase notification? using key value pairs?
I want to send a push notification to users asking them to update the app and when they tap on it, I want them to go to App store/ Playstore.
How can I add a URL on a firebase notification? using key value pairs?
Can someone help please?

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175655/android-push-notification-url and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145378/send-url-in-push-notification-firebase
