# Redirect android/ios push notifications to browser

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap

I have developed mobile app using phonegap for both andriod and ios. I used to send push notifications.

I can able to handle the notifications inside the app but some times i need to give my website link. If users click on the notification, link should open in browser. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: The answer here might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232288/opening-a-browser-link-through-notification-isnt-working

Comment: Where i have to put those codes? Those codes looks like native app. My application developed using phoengap.

Comment: put these where you build the notificatilon and set up along with the pending intent

Comment: link shared by Venkat does make sense