# How to open a link from a notification to my app?

Tags: android

Im trying to make my app open a link in the browser when a notification is recieved, but cant find a method that works with the app in foreground and in background.

The notification looks like this

```
  "notification": {
    "title": "My app try",
    "body": "This is a notification, YAY!",
  },
  "data": {
    "code":"1003",
    "url":"https://www.thisishard.com"
  }
```

If the app is closed I need to show the notification and when the user clicks on it, open the app and then open the browser.

But if the app is opened, I need to show the notification and only open the browser if the user clicks it.

Now it just opens the browser no metters what if the app is open and just opens the app if it is closed.

Im using firebase cloud messaging to send the notifications.

EDIT:

What I do is, in the onMessageReceived(), use an Intent to open the web browser

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String intentUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(intentUri));
        browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

Comment: There's not a whole lot of code here, so you'll have to show *what you tried*.

Comment: When you receive the message you need to create a Notification

Comment: @tadman I know, Dont have a lot of code because i just created an almost empty app implementing FCM. It just recives notifications and shows it if the app is in background.
Im looking for a guide or tutorial to do what i need but looks like a cant find one.

Comment: You're going to need to have *some* code or this question is premature and off-topic here.

Comment: @tadman Ok, i´ll edit showing what i have

Comment: Done. I believe I need a link to a guide or something like that because I seem to be unable to find one myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create own notification's onClick listener method like this

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); 
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
         // Resources r = getResources();
          Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                  .setTicker("yortext")
                  .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
                  .setContentTitle("yortext")
                  .setContentText("sdsd")
                  .setContentIntent(pi)
                  .setAutoCancel(true)
                  .build();

          NotificationManager notificationManager2 =  (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          notificationManager2.notify(0, notification);
```

> [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232288/opening-a-browser-link-through-notification-isnt-working)

Comment: Question.
If i do this when the app is in foreground, the notification created by te OS will open the app, and then the app will create a new notification?

Comment: I think yes.You can open url as soon as you receive new notification. Main idea is to test this code when app is foreground